# SOAP v_2 is not working getting 500 internal server error

Tags: soap, magento-1.9

When trying to login using soap v2 it giving 500 internal server error in magento.i checked the server error log file it is givving Access Denied  here are my codes.

this is the error on log file
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [2] Access denied. in /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/apitest.php:4\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/apitest.php(4): SoapClient->__call('login', Array)\n#1 /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/apitest.php(4): SoapClient->login('skulabs', 'api12345')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/apitest.php on line 4

These are my codes
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://example.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
print_r($proxy);
$sessionId = $proxy->login('skulabs', 'api12345'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary

$result = $proxy->catalogCategoryTree($sessionId);
var_dump($result);